# Clustering personal photos

Tags: photos

I just performed photo recovery on my compromised hard drive.
Now I have a folder with 20,000 photographs (each file has the same date)

I'd like to find a free piece of software that would cluster these photos into albums.

Since the date and GPS coordinates are lost, I'd expect the software to do it based on the photos composition and maybe resolution (I've had a number of different cameras in my life time)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [EXIFSORT](http://www.yawcam.com/exifsort/)

Then you can sort and break everything on EXIF.